# Apply specific layout PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an existing piece of code (see below) for importing a batch of photos and creating a slide show. At present, the code is creating these slides on a blank background with a title only. How can I modify it so it will choose a specific slide layout from the Master slides? I know it has something to do with this line in the code:
`Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)`

I looked here and tried some ideas but I just keep getting bugs: [Applying layout to a slide from specific Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049721/applying-layout-to-a-slide-from-specific-master)

Here's the full program:

```
Sub ImportStuffFromTextFile()
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oPic As Shape
Dim fs As Object
Dim f As Object
Dim PicDesc() As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
.Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = ActivePresentation.Path
If .Show = -1 Then
strFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End If
If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub
End With
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1, 0)
Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
    PicDesc = Split(f.readline, Chr(9))
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=PicDesc(0), _
                                      LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                      SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                      Left:=0, _
                                      Top:=0)
    If oSld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        oSld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = PicDesc(1)
        With oPic
            .Height = 469.875
            .Width = 626.325
            .Left = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width / 2
            .Top = oSld.Shapes.Title.Top + oSld.Shapes.Title.Height + 7
        End With
    End If
    Set oPic = Nothing
    Set oSld = Nothing
Loop
Set f = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you keep getting bugs, what do you mean?

- Are you getting error messages? If so, what are the error numbers/descriptions? Where does the code break?
- If not, and you're getting 'bugs', what should the final output look like and how does this differ from that?

I would say that one big unknown here is the text file input. According to your code, it seems as though it needs to have a series of filenames and corresponding picture descriptions on each line of the text file, separated by a tab. Critically, it must be a tab and not 2 spaces or 4 spaces or 10 spaces or a hyphen ... it must be a tab. Is that the structure of the text file you're using as input?

Comment: The code works properly as-is, however it applies the photos using one of the default slide layouts/templates and I want it to use a custom template.

I tried replacing "ppLayoutTitleOnly" with "ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)" but I'm getting this bug:
RunTimeError 438 Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: OK, well that's helpful. I'd say that the method causing the problem and giving this error is the .add point. Checking the MS documentation, it should be .addSlide, no?

Comment: Here is the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide - there is sample there too which does what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm a total VBA novice, I didn't write the original code myself. I tried making this modification:
```Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout))```
and now the error says: Run-time error 424 object required

Comment: Ok, but did you define pptlayout anywhere in your revised code? You sample code on the site I referred you to, you can see in the preceding line that pptylayout has been defined as ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout, you need to do something like that. Where is your custom layout? Have you given it a name? is it one of the slides?

Comment: Borrowing from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049721/applying-layout-to-a-slide-from-specific-master
From my understanding the layout I'm looking for is #2 under the first master slide list, so I added:
```Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, pptLayout)```

I'm back to Error 438

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint treats built-in layouts differently than custom ones. You can't call a custom layout by name. Instead, you have to loop through each custom layout to find the one that has the right name, then use it:

```
Sub AddSlideFromCustomLayout()
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    For Each oLayout In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If oLayout.Name = "Custom Layout Name" Then
            Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, oLayout)
        End If
    Next oLayout
End Sub
```

Here's your listing with the code replacing the **Set oSld** line:

```
Sub ImportStuffFromTextFile()
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oPic As Shape
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim PicDesc() As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ActivePresentation.Path
        If .Show = -1 Then
            strFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End If
        If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    End With
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1, 0)
    Do While Not f.AtEndOfStream
        PicDesc = Split(f.readline, Chr(9))
        For Each oLayout In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
            If oLayout.Name = "Custom Layout Name" Then
                Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, oLayout)
            End If
        Next oLayout
        Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=PicDesc(0), LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0)
        If oSld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
            oSld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = PicDesc(1)
            With oPic
                .Height = 469.875
                .Width = 626.325
                .Left = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 2 - .Width / 2
                .Top = oSld.Shapes.Title.Top + oSld.Shapes.Title.Height + 7
            End With
        End If
        Set oPic = Nothing
        Set oSld = Nothing
    Loop
    Set f = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: John, as a total VBA novice, can you kindly tell me how/where I should fit this new code into the existing code?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add the code in position in your listing

Comment: Thanks John! With the revised code, I'm now seeing run-time error 91"Object variable or With block variable not set". Looks like the issue is on the line with "Set oPic"

Comment: That would be a different issue than your original question. What's the value of PicDesc(0) when that line runs?

Comment: PicDesc(0) has the path and filename of the image. PicDesc(1) has the associated text
https://imgur.com/Y0aJBV9

Comment: I guess you double-checked that the file name and path point to a real picture.

Comment: Yes, I used the same input file to confirm the original code is working properly

Comment: John, any other suggestions I can try to debug things?